# I get NullPointerException in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Hello I get NullPointerException in this program can you help me ? Author class has private attributes and getter setter methods. Fileoperations class read a file and use stringtokenizer to split line by line. I getting an error at " athr[0].setId(tempId); " line. When i read from file tempId equals 100. I think problem is at Autor class but I couldn't fix that.

### Author

```
public class Author {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String univ;
    private String depart;
    private String email;
    private String article[] = new String[5];
    private int artCtr=0;

    public int getArtCtr() {
        return artCtr;
    }

    public void setArtCtr(int artCtr) {
        this.artCtr = artCtr;
    }

    FileOperations flp =new FileOperations();

    public String getArticle(int nmb) {
        return article[nmb];
    }

    public void setArticle(String article,int nmb) {
        this.article[nmb] = article;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUniv() {
        return univ;
    }

    public void setUniv(String univ) {
        this.univ = univ;
    }

    public String getDepart() {
        return depart;
    }

    public void setDepart(String depart) {
        this.depart = depart;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }



}
```

### FileOperations

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class FileOperations {

    Author athr[] = new Author[500];
    int athCtr = 0;
    int flag = 0;
    String temp;
    int tempId;

    public void strAthr(String path) throws IOException {
        String metin = "Suheyb";
        System.out.println(path);
        FileReader fl = new FileReader(path);

        try (BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(fl)) {

            while (metin != null) {
                metin = read.readLine();
                if (metin != null) {
                    StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(metin, "/t ");

                    if (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                        temp = str.nextToken();
                        tempId = Integer.parseInt(str.nextToken());
                        System.out.println(tempId + " " + athCtr);

                        if (athCtr != 0) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < athCtr; i++) {
                                if (athr[i].getId() == tempId) {
                                    flag = 1;
                                    if (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                                        athr[i].setName(str.nextToken());
                                        if (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                                            athr[i].setDepart(str.nextToken());
                                            if (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                                                athr[i].setEmail(str
                                                        .nextToken());
                                                if (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                                                    athr[i].setArticle(
                                                            str.nextToken(), 0);
                                                    athr[i].setArtCtr(1);
                                                    if (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                                                        athr[i].setArticle(
                                                                str.nextToken(),
                                                                1);
                                                        athr[i].setArtCtr(2);
                                                        if (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                                                            athr[i].setArticle(
                                                                    str.nextToken(),
                                                                    2);
                                                            athr[i].setArtCtr(3);
                                                            if (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                                                                athr[i].setArticle(
                                                                        str.nextToken(),
                                                                        3);
                                                                athr[i].setArtCtr(4);
                                                                if (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                                                                    athr[i].setArticle(
                                                                            str.nextToken(),
                                                                            4);
                                                                    athr[i].setArtCtr(5);
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            if (flag != 0) {
                                flag = 0;
                                athr[athCtr].setId(tempId);
                                if (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                                    athr[athCtr].setName(str.nextToken());
                                    if (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                                        athr[athCtr].setDepart(str.nextToken());
                                        if (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                                            athr[athCtr].setEmail(str
                                                    .nextToken());
                                            if (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                                                athr[athCtr].setArticle(
                                                        str.nextToken(), 0);
                                                athr[athCtr].setArtCtr(1);
                                                if (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                                                    athr[athCtr].setArticle(
                                                            str.nextToken(), 1);
                                                    athr[athCtr].setArtCtr(2);
                                                    if (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                                                        athr[athCtr]
                                                                .setArticle(
                                                                        str.nextToken(),
                                                                        2);
                                                        athr[athCtr]
                                                                .setArtCtr(3);
                                                        if (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                                                            athr[athCtr]
                                                                    .setArticle(
                                                                            str.nextToken(),
                                                                            3);
                                                            athr[athCtr]
                                                                    .setArtCtr(4);
                                                            if (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                                                                athr[athCtr]
                                                                        .setArticle(
                                                                                str.nextToken(),
                                                                                4);
                                                                athr[athCtr]
                                                                        .setArtCtr(5);
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                athCtr++;

                            }

                        }

                        else {
                            System.out.println(tempId);
                            athr[0].setId(tempId);
                            System.out.println(athr[0].getId());
                            if (str.hasMoreTokens()) {

                                athr[athCtr].setName(str.nextToken());
                                if (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                                    athr[athCtr].setDepart(str.nextToken());
                                    if (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                                        athr[athCtr].setEmail(str.nextToken());
                                        if (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                                            athr[athCtr].setArticle(
                                                    str.nextToken(), 0);
                                            athr[athCtr].setArtCtr(1);
                                            if (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                                                athr[athCtr].setArticle(
                                                        str.nextToken(), 1);
                                                athr[athCtr].setArtCtr(2);
                                                if (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                                                    athr[athCtr].setArticle(
                                                            str.nextToken(), 2);
                                                    athr[athCtr].setArtCtr(3);
                                                    if (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                                                        athr[athCtr]
                                                                .setArticle(
                                                                        str.nextToken(),
                                                                        3);
                                                        athr[athCtr]
                                                                .setArtCtr(4);
                                                        if (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                                                            athr[athCtr]
                                                                    .setArticle(
                                                                            str.nextToken(),
                                                                4);
                                                athr[athCtr]
                                                        .setArtCtr(5);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }


enter code here

        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            athCtr++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide the complete stack trace, and mark up the code to point out where the lines mentioned in the stacktrace are.

Comment: 1) That is some mean-ass level of nesting you have there!  (I'm just saying..) 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  3) Copy/paste the error message.

Comment: check the type of `tempId` the setter is expecting `int` and you probably feed him `string` can you post the function that creates the Author class ?

Comment: tempId = Integer.parseInt(str.nextToken()); is it wrong?

Comment: Add @d.raev (or whoever) to notify them of a new comment.

Answer (score 1):

You only have Defines the array of `Authors`. But you haven't initialized the elements. (As I can see :P)
`Author athr[] = new Author[500];` is not enough for reference type arrays.
use this after that line;

```
   for(int z=0;z<athr.length;z++){
     athr[z]=new Author();
   }
```

This should work.

Comment: I'm sorry.. Don't put that code under that line. :| put it inside `public void strAthr(...){`

Answer (score 1):

Your array doesn't have any elements!
you just declared it but you didn't initialize it! 
Author athr[] =new Author[500];
now that array doesn't have any data, all the elements are null! 
now when you are trying to use a element, you get NullPointException! 
now first take

```
    Author a= new Author(); 
    a.setName("bro");
    a.setId(123);
    arthr[0]=a; // you have an element in the first Index!
               // now, you want to initialize all
    for(int i=0; i< arthr.length; i++){
      arthr[i] =new Author();
      arthr[i].setName("bro");//you can set and get names, id's etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared an array, of type `Author[]`. This is not what you think it is. What you have effectively told the JVM is "Reserve this space for 500 Author Objects", but you have not specified those objects. So after:

```
Author athr[] = new Author[500];
```

You have an array that looks like this:

```
{null, null, null.... null} // From 0 to 500.
```

You then need to populate this array, by giving those reference types something to refer to, with the `new` keyword.

```
athr[32] = new Author();
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with this answer, than we need to initial use array element before using it.

```
for(int z=0;z<athr.length;z++){
     athr[z]=new Author();
   }
```

But it looks like you are processing TSV file and storing data in Author object.

The simplest way to achieve this with less complexity would be

[apache common csv example](http://www.baeldung.com/apache-commons-csv)

It’s would really ease your program. It’s worth of having look as it.

### ## book.csv ##

author,title

Dan Simmons,Hyperion

Douglas Adams,The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy

---

### code to read csv

```
List<Author> authList = ArrayList<>();
Author author = null;
Reader in = new FileReader("book.csv");
    Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.parse(in);
    for (CSVRecord record : records) {
        author = new Author();
        author.setAuthor(record.get(0));
        author.setTitle(record.get(1));
        authList.add(author);
    }
```